# C2675 unary operator caused by wrong scope

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am currently working on my own Vector class for the purpose of learning C++ and got stuck here.

The error happens in my implementation of the overloaded `-=` operator. Because the subtraction of two vectors is similar to adding two vectors but using the negative, I try to reuse the code from the `+=` operator by utilizing the `-` operator. Little confusing to write... so what I mean here... instead of directly implementing

`v1 - v2`

I want to implement

`v1 + (-v2)`

This is the code stripped down to the essential parts:

```
class Vector3 {
public:
    float m_x, m_y, m_z;

public:
    // creates a zero Vector3 (Vector3 with a magnitude of zero )
    Vector3()
        : m_x(0), m_y(0), m_z(0) {}

    // adds Vector3 v to this Vector3
    Vector3& operator +=(const Vector3& v) {
        m_x = v.m_x;
        m_y = v.m_y;
        m_z = v.m_z;
        return *this;
    }

    // substracts Vector3 v from this Vector3
    Vector3& operator -=(const Vector3& v) {
        return this->operator+=(-v);   // <--------ERROR
    }
};

// returns a clone of Vector3 v which is the negative of v
inline Vector3 operator -(const Vector3& v) {
    return Vector3(-v.m_x, -v.m_y, -v.m_z);
}
```

The error happens in the marked line and reads: `C2675 unary '-': 'const MathLib::Vector3' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`.

and the minus of `-v` is marked by it.

I am aware of the fact that it is maybe easier to just directly implement the `-=` without reusing other functions but this is for the previous mentioned learning purpose and I guess that I miss something crucial regarding C References here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your `operator+=(const Vector3& v)`. It performs assignment, but not the addition.

As for the unary `-` operator, if you want to use it in the class body, it should be accessible from the class body. Basically, you need to define you unary `-` operator

```
Vector3 operator-() const noexcept {
    return Vector3(-m_x, -m_y, -m_z);
}
```

before `operator-=`.

Comment: Thank you! Of course, the scope...

Because I cannot have an overloaded operator inside the Vector3 class AND outside of it, I will go with my inline function outside the class, but change the -= operator to return the following:

return this->operator+=(Vector3(-v.m_x, -v.m_y, -v.m_z));